# How to open a .py file from a remote server (Putty) in notepad/jupyter?

Tags: python

I am trying to access a python project structure residing on a remote server. I've connected to the remote server using Putty and I am able to see all the files. However, I would like to open the entire set of files as a project in an IDE.
When I try "python file.py", the file starts running rather than opening.

I'd appreciate a way to either open the files individually in notepad/jupyter or a suggestion for what IDE to use and how to open all the files in that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP integrates with Putty, has its own editor, and allows you to browse folder structures. Vscode also has an SSH extension you can try.

Otherwise, look into Vscode Server or running JupyterLab *on the remote server* and editing your code via your local browser if you want a more full IDE experience

Comment: The problem is that I cannot make changes to the remote server, as I am only meant to be reading through the code. Will using WinSCP change any configuration on the remote server?

Comment: WinSCP is a client application only. Doesn't affect the server (accept adding the ssh key, which would already have been done with Putty)

Comment: Alright, just tried it and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 2):

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) works and has been mentioned; you similarly ssh into the remote server and can access the files. This will work with your favorite file editor.

Another suggestion is using [Remote Development using SSH on VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) where you can ssh from VSCode and you should be able to get to the file system on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Putty will never let you open an IDE, you can run `nano file.py`, you can see the file, edit and save. you can copy the code to your local in an IDE and then paste it back there. you can use your remote IP and port and transfer files using SCP on the PowerShell

Comment: If you setup X.org Server, Putty can display GUI windows

Comment: I tried to use ssh -X remotely to open a qt5 gui before and it didn't work, to have a quick route I added a team viewer to access it on the main Linux OS

Answer (score 0):

Running GUI software on remote server, that's what you want.
You need to figure out a way to redirect XServer
One way is to use
"ssh -X"
the option -X will do some work for you.